# SQLiteDataAdapter Reading Multiple Date Time Formats (.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I've been writing a utility in VB to read various SQLite Tables...and until now, it's worked great. My problem is that in some databases there are "standard" date/time values...in others UNIX (or similar to Unix but a different start date/epoch).

I'm simply trying to read what is in the database and display it...I don't even want a conversion. I can get it to display the Unix times (but it translates to a standard M/D/Y type format)...I just want to see the numbers...same if it is in a M/D/Y type format, I want to see what's there. Make sense?

I'm having a hell of a time, and can't find anything that narrows it down for me, so I decided to post looking for help.

This is what I've got...

```vb
'Declare the main SQLite data access objects
Dim objConn As SQLiteConnection
Dim objCommand As SQLiteCommand
Dim objReader As SQLiteDataReader
'SQLiteDateFormats.UnixEpoch

Dim CONNECTION_STR As String = "Data Source=" & FileName & "; Version = 3; Read Only = True;" 'DateTimeFormat=UnixEpoch;"

TableName = "[" & TableName & "]"

Try
    'Create a new database connection
    objConn = New SQLiteConnection(CONNECTION_STR)

    'Open the connection
    objConn.Open()

    'Prepare Commands to Run
    objCommand = objConn.CreateCommand()

    'Determine Size of Table
    CommandToRun = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & TableName & ";"
    objCommand.CommandText = CommandToRun
    Dim RowCount As Long = objCommand.ExecuteScalar
    lblRowCount.Text = RowCount

    'Create a new SQL command to read all records from the selected table
    CommandToRun = "Select * From " & TableName & ";"
    objCommand.CommandText = CommandToRun

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(objCommand)
        da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        da.Fill(ds, TableName)

    End Using
    dgSQLite.DataSource = ds.Tables(TableName)
    dgSQLite.AutoResizeRows()
    dgSQLite.AutoResizeColumns()

    Me.Refresh()
Catch ex As Exception
        MyErrorBox(ex)
    End If
Finally
    'Cleanup and close the connection
    If Not IsNothing(objConn) Then
        objConn.Close()
        objConn.Dispose()
    End If
End Try
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: SQLite has a number of DateTime options.  First read [ask] and take the [tour], then how is the column defined in the DB?

Comment: I'm aware there are multiple DateTime options...that's the problem. This one utility will be opening multiple databases that each use different formats.

The one I'm trying to read now that indicated to me there was a problem is TimeStamp. It errors out if I don't open the connection with DateTimeFormat as UnixEpoch ... but when it's put in the datagridview it converts it so it displays in HH:mm:ss - I just want to see the actual UnixEpoch Value.

Comment: If you want to see the dbstore you will need to use a browser tool, or write a low level reader. Otherwise the NET DB provider performs transforms on the data.  A UnixDate of `1305149940` for example gets converted to a NET DateTime which displays to humans in some form of `m/d/y`  depending on the local culture.  if your tool is to read multiple DBs using different date storage types, you'll need to know that to make much sense from the data

Comment: ...and the column datatype may not be inconsequential to some of what you may be trying to do